# UICollectionView image gallery app

Tags: ios, swift

I built an app that allows users to add and remove images in a collection view. I want this to be useful online so I save the images into a database and retrieve them every time. I'm looking for constructive criticism on how I solved this problem. It is in swift. The code works just fine, but I notice some lag sometimes, and it may be because of the way I designed the software. This is why I'm looking for criticism.

ViewGallery.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import DKImagePickerController

class ViewGallery: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let db = Firebase(url: "mydatabaseurl")
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

 var imageDatas: [String] = []
 var selectedItems: [NSIndexPath] = []
 var keys: [AnyObject] = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  db.childByAppendingPath("Images").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
    snapshot in
    let images = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
    self.keys = images.allKeys
    self.imageDatas = []
    for key in self.keys {
      self.imageDatas.append(images[key as! NSString as String]!["image"] as! String)
    }
    self.selectedItems = []
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  })
}

@IBAction func addPictures(sender: AnyObject) {
  let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

  pickerController.didSelectAssets = { [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
    print("didSelectAssets")
    for asset in assets {
      let imageData = asset.rawData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
      self.saveImageStringToDatabase(imageData!)
    }
  }

  self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func removePicture(sender: AnyObject) {
  for indexPath in selectedItems {
    db.childByAppendingPath("Images").childByAppendingPath(self.keys[indexPath.item] as! String).removeValue()
  }
}

func saveImageStringToDatabase(imageString: String) {
  let value = ["image": imageString]
  db.childByAppendingPath("Images").childByAutoId().setValue(value)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if imageDatas.count == 0 {
    return 0
  } else {
    return imageDatas.count
  }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  if imageDatas.count == 0 {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("View Gallery Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
  } else {
    let base64String = self.imageDatas[indexPath.item]
    let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
    let decodedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("View Gallery Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.imageView.image = decodedImage
    return cell
  }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ImageCell
  if selectedItems.contains(indexPath) {
    print("unselected")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let indexToBeDeleted = selectedItems.indexOf(indexPath)
    selectedItems.removeAtIndex(indexToBeDeleted!)
  } else {
    print("selected")
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    selectedItems.append(indexPath)
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Purely "FTR".  It's probably better to use Parse than Firebase for just this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Firebase or DKImagePickerController framework, so I cannot say anything
about that. But there are some things that I noticed:

There is no need in Swift to reference properties via `self`
(unless there is an ambiguity with a local variable, e.g. in an init
method). And you are not consistent here, e.g. both `self.selectedItems`
and `selectedItems` is used.

---

This

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if imageDatas.count == 0 {
        return 0
    } else {
        return imageDatas.count
    }
}
```

can be simplified to

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageDatas.count
}
```

And in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

there is no need to check for `imageDatas.count == 0` (and return a dummy cell in that case). If the array
is empty then `numberOfItemsInSection` returns zero, i.e. the
collection view displays no item at all and `cellForItemAtIndexPath`
will not be called.

---

If the *order* of the selected items is not relevant then you can
use a *set* instead of an array:

```
var selectedItems = Set<NSIndexPath>()
```

Adding or removing an index path then simplifies slightly to

```
if selectedItems.contains(indexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    selectedItems.remove(indexPath)
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    selectedItems.insert(indexPath)
}
```

---

A loop like

```
self.imageDatas = []
for key in self.keys {
    self.imageDatas.append(...)
}
```

can be replaced by a mapping:

```
self.imageDatas = self.keys.map { key in ... }
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for taking the time to look at my code. Is it best practice to turn images into base64 string and saving it into a database, then to view it by retrieving the base64 string and converting it back into an image? What do you think? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @user3904534: Usually storing the image data directly as a binary blob is to be preferred. That saves space and computation. But as I said, I don't know Firebase, therefore I did not cover that part.